# Why does djangos json serializer work but not pythons?

Tags: python, json, django

can someone please explain to me whats happening here and whats the difference between these 2 functions. I am essentially trying to return a django object to my angular controller and so the response has to be in json.

```
obj = Cuisine.objects.all()
print obj
[<Cuisine: Chinese>, <Cuisine: Indian>, <Cuisine: Japanese>]
```

With django serializer

```
from django.core import serializers
obj_json = serializers.serialize('json', obj)
print obj_json
[{"pk": 1, "model": "swings.cuisine", "fields": {"name": "Chinese"}}, {"pk": 2, "model": "swings.cuisine", "fields": {"name": "Indian"}}, {"pk": 3, "model": "swings.cuisine", "fields": {"name": "Japanese"}}]
```

With python json, why is it unable to convert my object to json here?

```
import json
obj_json = json.dumps(obj)
TypeError: TypeErro...izable',)
```

Now django-angular has a JSONResponseMixin which automatically converts the returned object / list to json but it keeps giving me a type error. I have a feeling its connected to the same reason why json.dumps does work. I've been reading around plenty trying all sorts of work arounds to no luck. I have already tried converting my object to a list first via list(obj) but that does nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Django actually processes the queryset recursively to generate the serialized data, where as python's does not. Source: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/serializers/base.py#L35